# Ember-cli and Google Maps Search

Tags: google-maps, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm new in ember and recently I encounter some difficulties.
I'm trying to use google map autocomplete. In my JavaScript example everything works great.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Autocomplete</title>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var options = {
                types: ['(cities)']
            };
            var input = document.getElementById('searchField');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="searchField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Location..." autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But in my ember application when i select location with my mouse input box value is not changing  (it works only for keyboard). For example. I'm writing *New Yo*, and then select *New York* from drop down list but my value is still *New Yo*

This is my code:

*app/components/gmap-search.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    searchTextField: function() {
            var options = {
                    types: ['(cities)']
                };
            var input = this.$('.search-field')[0];
            new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

*app/templates/components/gmap-search.hbs*

```
{{input class="search-field form-control" type="text" value=offer.location placeholder="" required="required"}}
```

*app/templates/application.hbs*

```
{{gmap-search offer=offer }}
```

I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem arises when submitting data to the server? It certainly should help:

```
submit: function() {
    this.set('offer.location', this.$('.search-field')[0].value);
    ... 
}
```